# Convert concatenated columns to date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

How can I convert this piece of code into a date. I'm using a day column to create a date using the code below in TSQL.

```
convert(nvarchar(2),a.ucdaycode) + '/' +
    cast(month(GETDATE()) as varchar) + '/' +
    cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar)
```

Has anybody any any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Look at the SQL Server `convert` function doc page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 The third parameter is for the date & time style.There are loads of style options.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    a.ucdaycode,
    DATEADD(dd, a.ucdaycode, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS some_date
FROM yourTable a;
```

[image]

### Demo

The answer by @Zohar looks a bit cleaner than this, but it might only run on SQL Server 2012 or later.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for this. If the ucdaycode is 2 the date needs to be 02-01-2019 i.e. it needs to fall on the same date but seems to be incrementing by 1.

Comment: Thanks Tim, This really helped, I've manged to get what I wanted.

Comment: @user3306489 if an answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), a.ucdaycode)
```

Comment: datefromparts is not a builtin function on sql server 2008

Comment: Well, this goes to show you that you should specify the version in the question....